# How do I narrow down the distinct rows based on column filters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to search for the most recent occurrences of a bunch of transactions but only want one return of each transaction. My attempt at the code prob explains it better than I can.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT    TransactionCode
    ,       IdKey 
FROM        TransTable 
WHERE       TransactionCode IN (<massive list of ids...>) 
AND         ActionDate      < GETDATE() 
ORDER BY    ActionDate DESC
```

I want one instance of each transaction code, ordered by date (*aka the most recent occurrence of that transaction*) and the idKey returned also. Thoughts?

Comment: Unique is applied to the table isn't it? I can't alter the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT TransactionCode, 
       IdKey
FROM
  (
    SELECT TransactionCode, 
           IdKey,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TransactionCode 
                             ORDER BY ActionDate DESC) AS rn
    FROM TransTable 
    WHERE TransactionCode in (1,2,3) AND 
          ActionDate < GETDATE() 
  ) T
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: I think the subselect should also return `ActionDate`, as the OP seems to want to sort the result set by it.

Comment: @AndriyM It could be so. I interpreted the `order by` clause as an attempt to only get the "last" row for each `TransactionCode` not as a sort order for the resultset.

Comment: Think this is it, thanks v much. Not particularly familiar with partitioning, must take a closer look now! 'order by' was my attempt to get the last/latest row.

Comment: @user1365650 - [Here is the documentation for row_number() over()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign row number to each row in the table by partitioning them on `TransactionCode` column and then sort them by `ActionDate` in the descending order so that you get the latest transaction in the top on the section. Once the row numbers are assigned based on this logic, you can filter out only the rows that have the `rownum` value of **1** from the derived table output. This will fetch all the transaction codes. You can add the filter condition in the below query according to your requirement.

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59fa2/1)

*Script*:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TransTable
(
        IdKey           INT         NOT NULL IDENTITY
    ,   TransactionCode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    ,   ActionDate      DATETIME    NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.TransTable (TransactionCode, ActionDate) VALUES
    ('code 1', '2012-04-27 01:04:12.467'),
    ('code 1', '2012-04-22 09:16:29.354'),
    ('code 2', '2012-04-12 11:04:27.751'),
    ('code 1', '2012-06-19 12:27:12.232'),
    ('code 2', '2012-04-04 05:22:17.467'),
    ('code 3', '2012-05-01 08:49:12.951'),
    ('code 3', '2012-05-13 06:12:12.234');

SELECT  IdKey
    ,   TransactionCode
    ,   ActionDate
FROM
(
    SELECT  IdKey
        ,   TransactionCode
        ,   ActionDate
        ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                        PARTITION  BY TransactionCode 
                        ORDER BY ActionDate DESC
            ) rownum
    FROM    dbo.TransTable
    WHERE   ActionDate < GETDATE()
) t1 WHERE rownum = 1;
```

*Output*:

```
IdKey TransactionCode ActionDate
----- --------------- -----------------------
1     code 1          2012-04-27 01:04:12.467
3     code 2          2012-04-12 11:04:27.750
```

Answer (score 1):

May be, you can find it like this:

```
;WITH Cte AS (
SELECT 
    ROW_Number() over (partition by TransactionCode, IdKey  ORDER BY ActionDate DESC) RowID,
    TransactionCode, IdKey      
FROM TransTable 
WHERE TransactionCode in (Massive list of IDs) 
AND ActionDate < GETDATE() 
)
SELECT * FROM Cte WHERE RowID = 1
```